# Add external html template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using a directive to inject some specific content on my page. We have a requirement when the url attribute points to an html file and the contents of that file need to be rendered on my page. How can I do that

```
<section>
<block-with-html 
url = "locatiion of html file">
</block-with-html>
</section>

angular
.module('app.blockWithHtml', [])
.directive('blockWithHtml', BlockWithHtmlDirective);

 function BlockWithHtmlDirective(ConfigBlocksService) {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
       url: '='
     },
     template: `
       <section  >
         <h4>block with html</h4>
         <div>content form the html file goes here</div>
       </section>
     `,
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to pass fields which are not expressions, try this:

   ```
      <section>
          <block-with-html 
             type='image'
             url = "locataion of html file">
             </block-with-html>
       </section>

       angular
       .module('app.blockWithHtml', [])
       .directive('blockWithHtml', BlockWithHtmlDirective);

        function BlockWithHtmlDirective(ConfigBlocksService) {

       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           template: function(tElement,tAttr){
              //Use the tAttr.url 
             var imageTemplate   = '<img src="tAttr.url">';
             var dynamicTemplate = '<ng-include src=”getTemplateUrl(tAttr.url)”/>';

           return tAttr.type == 'image' ? imageTemplate : dynamicTemplate;
           }
           controller: function($scope) {
              $scope.getTemplateUrl = function(url) {
              //Some logic here..
           }
       }
       };
   ```
2. If you asking that the source template of the directive will be set "on the fly" according to a passed expression - **it is not possible**.
   The reason is that the template of the directive is being set on the **compilation phase** - this is where angularjs is 'opening' the template of all the directives and putting them on dom **but the scope is not being created yet , this will happen in the link phase** where angularjs goes over each directive's template and create a scope for it and bind all the events.
   **For summary, you can't pass a template location based on an expression.**

Comment: I'm not asking about the source template. I want to replace the div in the source template with the html content which I receive as a url parameter. if the url points to a image that that will be rendered in the block. In my case the url points to an html file , so I need to render the content of this file. Thanks for any help regarding this.

Comment: Answer edited - tell me if this what you're looking for.